# run PM2 command from shell_exec (PHP) not working

Tags: php, node.js, pm2, shell-exec

I have tried

```
var_dump(shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/pm2 2>&1"));
```

when in run from browser, its show an error :

> [PM2][Initialization] Environment variable HOME (Linux) or HOMEPATH (Windows) are not set! [PM2][Initialization] Defaulting to /etc/.pm2

i have tried set path export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/pm2" but it didnt works

Comment: Make sure that you have set the necessary permission (you said you are running the command on a browser)

Comment: try to use system method